# handling select dropdown menu in php

Tags: php, html

I put a first option in my select element just to tell the user what they are selecting, I think it's advisable to put a null first option, but I want to put an error message that the user didnt select anything if he is just selecting the first option which is the null option here's my code

```
<select class = "strand" name = "strand">
        <option >=====Strand=====</option>
        <option value ="GAS">GAS</option>
        <option value ="ICT">ICT</option>
        <option value ="STEM">STEM</option>
        <option value ="HUMSS">HUMMSS</option>
        <option value ="ABM">ABM</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Assign it a unique `value=NULL` and either check server-side, and/or per JavaScript before submission.

Comment: Options without an explicit value have the inner HTML as value. `value=""` and PHP `if(empty($_POST['strand'])` (or _GET)